# Can anyone spot the SQL issue here? Trying to update fields in ms-access

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

```
Dim sqlUpdate As String

sqlUpdate = "UPDATE [Stock Conversion] SET [Stock Conversion].Status = 'PRINTED' " & _
"WHERE ((([Stock Conversion].Status) = 'NEW'));"

' Turn off warning
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'Run SQL
DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlUpdate)

'Turn on warning
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Basically there is no error message, it's just nothing happens at all?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have any records with status = 'NEW'?  Also, why all the parentheses?

Comment: I do, and I read that access likes parentheses :P

Comment: Try with Warnings on to see if the message provides you with any additional information.  Also, please post a few rows of real sample data from your database before and after the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste this statement into SQL View of a new Access query and test it.

```
UPDATE [Stock Conversion]
SET Status = 'PRINTED'
WHERE Status = 'NEW';
```

If it doesn't work, hopefully the error message will help you understand why so you can fix it.

If it does work correctly, execute the same statement from VBA using the `.Execute` method of a DAO.Database object.  Since you won't be using `DoCmd.RunSQL`, there is no motivation to turn `SetWarnings` off.  And that's an important point because you suppress information when you turn `SetWarnings` off.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim sqlUpdate As String

sqlUpdate = "UPDATE [Stock Conversion]" & vbCrLf & _
    "SET Status = 'PRINTED'" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE Status = 'NEW';"
Debug.Print sqlUpdate
DoCmd.SetWarnings True ' in case it had been left off somehow '
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute sqlUpdate, dbFailOnError
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Hey Hans, sorry I've managed to get this working now, basically I wrote the code in a pre-coded button (print report) and I had written it at the end of the prewritten code without thinking, turns out I wrote it in the On_error section!

Comment: @BobP Glad you found the error, while your there though I suggest you amend your code slightly to the **execute** method mentioned by HansUp as this is better practice than turning the warnings off.

Answer (score 0):

somethings to help:

- remove `[Stock Conversion]` from the `set` and the `where`
- remove the unnecessary parentheses on the Where
- remove the semicolon
- check again.
- If it doesnt work, remove the `where` and try again to check if there
  is an issue with your were clause
- add a SQL trace to the database to see if the query is really being
  submited
- paste the complete SQL statment here so we can help more

Comment: I hardly believe he is doing that on a production database, he probably has a development database

Comment: I've seen a lot of places that used Access, going all the way back to version 1.0. I could count the ones that separated development from production on one hand. In any case, it's probably wise to mention that issue for those who come later, and who might not have isolated development from production.